# Why is BeautifulSoup's find_All method returning an empty list?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-analysis

I am trying to practice webscrapping on Google's Jobs webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=google+jobs&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS993US993&oq=google+jobs&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512j0i433i512l2j0i512j69i60l3.1100j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-9Mak9tX4AhVqIEQIHX7jCQgQutcGKAF6BAgDEAY&sxsrf=ALiCzsb2SZksAxw0NnFdLD3WRkzUb7z0PA:1656617817988#htivrt=jobs&htidocid=9DZhMax31VQAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D&fpstate=tldetail'
page = requests.get(url)
```

Everything is working fine up to this point. If I print the page variable, I get response 200.

Next,

```
pageContent = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
jobList = pageContent.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'BjJfJf PUpOsf'})
```

Now printing jobList just prints an empty list.

I've tried other formats:

```
jobList = pageContent.find_all('section', class_='BjJfJf PUpOsf')
jobList = pageContent.find_all('div', class_='BjJfJf PUpOsf')
jobList = pageContent.find_all('section', class_='BjJfJf PUpOsf')
jobList = pageContent.find_all('section', class_='BjJfJf PUpOsf ')
```

They all print an empty list as well.

So, I did further investigation and checked to see if the html produced in this line:

```
pageContent = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

...produced the same html with all the divs and what not. Even checked the divs of the html in pageContent:

```
contentDiv = pageContent.find_all("div")
for div in contentDiv:
    print(div.get("class"))
```

Obviously the class I am looking at, **BjJfJf PUpOsf**, wasn't listed. These were however:

```
None
None
['w43NHb']
['qDdeqd']
['diIKdd']
None
['SC3FEd']
['oLm9bf']
```

So, the html that was gathered through BeautifulSoup appears to be different from the html I see when I do inspect element on the page or when I view page source.

My question is, how can I actually access that class or any class that is formatted similar to it so I can print it to console or otherwise use it for gathering data for future analysis?

Comment: Just a guess but could be the website is loaded using JavaScript which does not get rendered out when using BS. You need to supply correct headers to trick it into thinking it's a browser

Comment: @JostB Why would making it think it's a browser prevent it from sending a dynamic web page?

Comment: I figured that might be the case as I faced a similar issue for a project that included webscraping about 1.5 years ago. But I was able to workaround the JS stuff with API calls instead. Your mentioning of supplying correct headers to trick it, would me searching YouTube/Google for "tricking headers" be sufficient for finding something I can work with or would you recommended a more specific resource for that?

Comment: Use a library like Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser, that will execute the JS.

Comment: You can have a look here https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-with-beautiful-soup-a-use-case-fc1c60c8005d @NicelyPenn

Comment: It's true that organizations might explicitly break pages when they detect a Python user agent, but it would generally not take the form seen here of a page half-loaded because JS hadn't executed. In cases like that, as Barmar pointed out, Selenium is a great way to go because it will use an actual browser client with JS engine to load the page the way a real user does.  Furthermore, simply changing the user agent string is likely not enough to deceive an adversary as sophisticated as Google, and even using Selenium is something can *theoretically* detect unless you write "humanizing" code.